# Display a related variable other than the related table's primary key (ID)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I wonder if you can help me discover how to a display a related model variable other than the related table's primary key (in this case the pk is a id and it is not very helpful).

Model:

```
[EdmRelationshipNavigationPropertyAttribute("PlantModel", "FK_PlantSoilpH_Plant", "PlantSoilpH")]
        public EntityCollection<PlantSoilpH> PlantSoilpHs
        {
            get
            {
                return ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.GetRelatedCollection<PlantSoilpH>("PlantModel.FK_PlantSoilpH_Plant", "PlantSoilpH");
            }
            set
            {
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    ((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection<PlantSoilpH>("PlantModel.FK_PlantSoilpH_Plant", "PlantSoilpH", value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Plants.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScientificName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantSoilpHs)
        </td>
```

My guess has been that I should just be able to add 'item.PlantSoilpHs.Name' but that doesn't seem to be the case. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

-Scott

Comment: `Plant.PlantSoilpHs` is a collection, isn't it? What do you want to display? A "nested" table with all names of `PlantSoilpH` or the name of just the first element in the collection or...?

Comment: I have 3 tables in the database: Plant, PlantSoilpH, and SoilpH. Plant is a table that contains: PlantID(PK) and PlantName. SoilpH is a table that contains: SoilpHID(PK) and SoilpHName. PlantSoilpH is a table that contains: PlantSoilpHID(PK), PlantID(FK/1:1), and SoilpHID(FK/Many:1). I don't know enough about collections to answer your question but what I'm trying to do is show the Plant's SoilpHName. What I'm getting instead is PlantSoilpHID. Noob here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can only guess: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlantSoilpHs.Select(p => p.SoilpH.Name))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather by analyzing your question and comments, you are using the View to return a list of Plant objects - which by your description only contain PlantID and PlantName. You can't return the SoilpHName this way. In order to get the SolpHName associated with a plant, instead of

```
return View(db.Plants.ToList());
```

you have to use

```
return View(db.PlantSoilpHs.ToList());
```

in the Controller and

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr> 
    <td> 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Plant.PlantName) 
    </td> 
    <td> 
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SoilpH.Name) 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Forgive me if the code is not accurate, it wasn't tested, and was provided only based on your problem description.